# Hook into USB RFID reader, bypassing keyboard wedge input

Tags: c#, vb.net, usb

I'm looking for a way to be able to trap input from a USB keyboard-wedge device so the application can process it, irrespective of form/control focus.

The scenario is this.

- USB-connected RFID reader which appears as a keyboard wedge (so no distinction at application level about where the characters have come from)
- Application has a text input box, which when the control has focus, happily takes the characters (as you would expect).

So, what I'm after is a way to hook in at USB device level and trap the data stream coming from the reader, thus the application would not need focus to still process the information (and I can remove the text input box).

Alternatively, is there any 3rd party software around that will do the hook and present a COM port to the system instead?

Using .Net (in this case VB, but solutions in VB or C# equally valid).

Jim

Comment: You can use `SerialPort` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) class for listening COM ports.
If this device works as a keyboard, you can create keyboard hook and listen to the "keys" that it sends, but then you will not be able to filter if the input is from your device or the real keyboard

Comment: But the device is a keyboard wedge, so (as I said above), I need to either hook into the USB device at a low level, or (if such software exists) use a 3rd party driver to expose the input as a COM port instead.